# How to pass user details to paypal sdk from node js application?

Tags: node.js, express, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using JWT in my node.js application, and I'm receiving payment requests from the authorized (logged in) users. I have added Paypal REST SDK to my application and I'm successfully redirecting to the success route after the payment succeed, but how can I determine which user made the payment?
I know I can use some values in the response about the payment, payer ID, and email. But I'm trying to figure out a better way to handle the situation where a user might pay from a different Paypal email.

Is there a way to pass maybe the user ID and receive it back in the success route? Do I miss something in this flow?

***POST*** request coming from VUE JS:

```
app.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
   var userId = req.userId; // from the authorization header of the requset 

  const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Red Sox Hat",
                "sku": "001",
                "price": "25.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        },
        "description": "Hat for the best team ever"
    }]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
  if (error) {
      throw error;
  } else {
      for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
        if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
          res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
        }
      }
  }
});

});
```

***Success*** route, where I want to access ***userId*** and store some information about the user and the payment in my database:

```
app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
  const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
  const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

  const execute_payment_json = {
    "payer_id": payerId,
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "25.00"
        }
    }]
  };

  paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
        res.send('Success');
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using a deprecated v1/payments SDK for which there is no support. Use the `Checkout-NodeJS-SDK` for v2/checkout/orders instead. See the documentation for 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order' here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls , these are the two routes you will need
2. To send data from the client to your server, add and include it as JSON-formatted POST data in the `fetch`/XHR call to your server from the client-side createOrder and captureOrder functions in this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  The data you add will then be parsable and available on your server handling that route, in `req`.
3. Since you are using VUE, you may find this driver useful: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/#vue , but note that the samples there are for a client-side create and capture. You should continue using routes on your server for these actions.